# How to select from 3 tables whilst joining to 2 others

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a table called `lwim_projects` with the column project_id (amongst others), a  table called `lwim_designers` with the column designer_id (amongst others) and a table called `lwim_images` with the column image_id (amongst others).

I also have 2 joining tables called `lwim_join_designers_projects` and `lwim_join_projects_images`.

The `lwim_join_designers_projects` has the columns:

- dp_id,
- designer_id and
- project_id

The `lwim_join_projects_images` has the columns:

- pi_id
- project_id and
- image_id.

I would like to join the joining tables with the tables mentioned earlier but unfortunately cannot seem to be able to join both, only one of them.

The code below looks right to me (and have tried many, many combinations of this).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lwim_projects, lwim_designers, lwim_images
INNER JOIN lwim_join_designers_projects ON lwim_join_designers_projects.designer_id = lwim_designers.designer_id
INNER JOIN lwim_join_projects_images ON lwim_join_projects_images.image_id = lwim_images.image_id
WHERE lwim_projects.project_id = lwim_join_designers_projects.project_id
AND lwim_projects.project_id = lwim_join_projects_images.project_id
ORDER BY date_repinned DESC
LIMIT 20");
```

I have also tried it without the second where statement.

Like I said it works without selecting from the lwim_images table and joining the images table and visa versa but doesn't seem to want to work for both.

Can anyone shed some light on where I may be going wrong?

Kind Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining 5 tables.  That generally means you need 4 INNER JOINS, unless you are joining in an unusual way.  Try rewriting your query with just one table in the FROM clause followed by four INNER JOIN clauses.  Each INNER JOIN needs an ON condition.

If I were debugging this,  I would try getting the query right using interactive SQL before embedding the query in code.

Edit to include answer (untested):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM lwim_designers
INNER JOIN lwim_join_designers_projects ON
 lwim_join_designers_projects.designer_id = lwim_designers.designer_id
INNER JOIN lwim_projects ON 
  lwim_projects.project_id = lwim_join_designers_projects.project_id
INNER JOIN lwim_join_projects_images ON
  lwim_join_projects_images.project_id = lwim_projects.project_id
INNER JOIN lwim_images ON
  lwim_images.image_id = lwim_join_projects_images.image_id 
ORDER BY date_repinned DESC
LIMIT 20");
```

It's awfully hard with these names to makes sure I haven't made a typo.

Comment: Ah I see many thanks for your answer it worked a treat (you have saved me a further 3 days worth of headaches). I will post my answer

Comment: It wont allow me to post the answer for 8 hours I will do it after the 8 hours is up

Comment: So, did you ever come up with working code?  If you can solve it for yourself after my hint, that's better!

Comment: Hi, Yes it worked great thanks, I have ticked the answer. Thank you very much Walter

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lwim_projects, lwim_designers, lwim_images
INNER JOIN lwim_join_designers_projects ON lwim_join_designers_projects.designer_id = lwim_designers.designer_id AND lwim_join_designers_projects.project_id = lwim_projects.project_id
INNER JOIN lwim_join_projects_images ON lwim_join_projects_images.image_id = lwim_images.image_id AND lwim_join_projects_images.project_id = lwim_projects.project_id
ORDER BY date_repinned DESC
LIMIT 20");
```

I've placed the where clause inside the `INNER JOIN ON` statement, mayby that helps...

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer but unfortunately I am still getting the same error Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

Comment: @DanielOrmerod, Try to see what mysqli gives for error. And did you try it to run directly onto the server ( through PHPMYADMIN )?

Comment: Hi Mathlight, I have tried running it as a mysqli_query and the following error is given  Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in...

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in...     I then tried as you suggested running it through phpmyadmin and the error it gives is #1054 - Unknown column 'lwim_designers.designer_id' in 'on clause' which is very strange as it definately does exist http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/4273/q6lk.jpg

Comment: @DanielOrmerod, you should use mysqli_* functions instead of the mysql_* functions, because mysql_* is deprecated. The change is that you have to give the DB connection as param 1, and the query as param 2.

And dit you tryed it with backtips `{`}` around the colloms?

Comment: Hi Mathlight, I got it sorted with Walter Mittys answer I will post the answer as soon as it lets me. And thank you for your suggestion I will begin to use mysqli functions from now on